# Why isn't my hamburger menu opening when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I tried to make a responsive nav bar for my website, but when the button to open the hamburger menu is clicked...nothing happens.

Here is the html pertaining to the nav bar

```
<header>
  <img class="logo" src = "Spotify_Logo.png" alt="logo">
  <nav>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Troubleshoot</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Use Now</button></a>
  
  
</header>
```

Now here is the CSS and the media screen for the hamburger menu

```
@media screen and (max-width: 870px){
  .toggle-button{
    display: flex;
  }
 
  .nav_links{
    display: none;
    width:100%;
  }
  .cta{
    display: none;
  }
  .nav_links{
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .nav_links{
    flex-direction:column
  }
  .nav_links li a{
    padding: .5rem 1 rem;
  }
  .nav_links:active{
    display:flex;
  }
}
```

And finally, the JS

```
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks=document.getElementsByClassName('nav_links')[0]


toggleButton.addEventListener('click', -> () {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

Any help is appreciated!

I have no clue why it isn't working. I changed the CSS around so it goes for the entire header, that didn't work. I believe that it might be something with the active tags in the CSS or something wrong in my JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Luke and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for new users that I recommend all new users take - you even get a badge for taking it! In the mean time, open the console and fix the JavaScript error shown (`->` should be `=>`). Also please convert the posted code into a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C40.3202) so readers can see how it does or doesn't work. Don't forget to remove the media rule for testing.

Answer (score 0):

1. there is the syntax error mentioned before
2. the button is currently not visible because of the media-query (I assume the hamburger is only for mobile, which is assume needs the button)
3. `navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active');` only adds a class called 'active' that you don't have defined.
   I suggest to use `navbarLinks.style = "display: flex;"` instead. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the selector of this rule...

```
.nav_links:active{
  display:flex;
}
```

... "active" needs to be a *class* in order to react to the class toggle triggered by your JS, i.e. it should not be `.nav_links:active` , but `.nav_links.active`